# how to do authorization (nodejs, express) with two tokens (access/refresh)

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, access-token, refresh-token

Good evening, I ran into a problem that I need to make authorization more secure and without re-logging. I read on the Internet that you need to use two tokens (access and refresh), but how to properly do authorization with them. You can advise a resource where competent authorization with two tokens is made.

My Tech Stack:

- **M**ongoDB
- **E**xpressJS
- **R**eactJS
- **N**odeJS

Comment: Are you using an authorization provider (e.g. okta, auth0, fusion auth) or are you working with OAuth/OICD on your own server?

Comment: On your own server

Answer (score 1):

If you request authentication with offline_access scope, you'll geta refresh token in addition to an access token. Save this refresh token to the database and whenever you need to make another call on behalf of the user you can

1. Make the call using your existing access token. If you don't get a 401, then you're good.
2. If you did get a 401, your token is probably expired and then you can call the token end point on the authorization server with the refresh token and grant_type=refresh_token to get a new access token and try your call again.

Might make the most sense to always request a new access token using your refresh token before you make another call.

Comment: You won't have any material with code examples ?

Comment: @Krytoi how are you authenticating right now?

Comment: I check the data for validation, search for an existing user, create a token, and give it to response

Comment: Do I need to store a refresh token on the client ?

Comment: @Krytoi NEVER store a refresh token on the client except in memory

Comment: @Krytoi if you are just trying to keep your user logged in, then you do that via cookies.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you only deal with access tokens for authorization.  The refresh token is only there to refresh an expired access token.  The refresh token is exchanged for a new access token - without needing to present authentication credentials again.  The call also (typically) takes a fraction of the time than re-authenticating.

Comment: @ScottMclntosh do I need to save the refresh token in the database? (I have this mongo)

Answer (score 0):

as soon as the user log-in, give it two tokens refresh and access, store the refresh token in the database, give access token a expire time (5-10 min approx or less depending on your requirement).
for each request user will use the access token and for each request backend should check for the expired access token.

if the access token is expired, user will get a new access token by sending the stored refresh token to the backend(using a dedicated endpoint), backend will than check whether the refresh token is present in the database or not, if yes a new access token with new expire time will be sent in the response.

the cycle will continue until the user logs-out, in that case the refresh token will be deleted from the database and after some time access token will also get expire.